# What is the difference between homogeneous Markov chains and unhomogeneous Markov chains?

Tags: markov-process, graphical-model, graph-theory

I learned that a Markov chain is a graph that describes how the state changes over time, and a homogeneous Markov chain is such a graph that its system dynamic doesn't change. Here the system dynamic is something also called transition kernel which means the calculation of the probability from one station to the next station.

I'm just wondering what the essential difference would be in concrete if we compare two Markov chains, one is homogeneous and the other one is not? All the Markov chains I have learned are homogeneous and it is hard for me intuit the unhomogeneous ones and I don't know their applications(in what kind of scenarios do we utilize them?).

If one could help instantiate the homogeneous Markov chains using a very simple real-world example and then change one condition to make it an unhomogeneous one, I would appreciate it very much.

Comment: In _homogeneous_ Markov Chains, the transition probabilities $p_{ij} = P(X_{n+1} = j\,|\,X_{n}=i),$ do not depend on $n.$ Thus, throughout the evolution of the process through time, the transitions among states follow the same probability rules. // In _non-homogeneous_ chains, transition probabilities can vary across time. // One might need to use non-homogeneous chains to model up and down ticks in the stock market as the financial environment changes between bull and bear markets.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks very much for your comment, but could you please flesh it into an answer? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what else I would say in Answer format. If you have further questions, please ask and one of us is likely to answer.

Comment: @BruceET OK, I will further delve into this issue and update my question. Thanks.